# Drupal 8 Private file is accessbile by anonymous user

Tags: users, files

I have created a content type with file field and set Upload destination is private files. I have also set the $settings['file_private_path'] = '/path/to/private'. But the file is accessible by anonymous user.

Comment: Is the node visible for anonymous users?

Comment: Yes node is visible.

Comment: I guess you mean the uploaded file itself is directly accessible when entering the URL in browser? If yes, add a `.htaccess` file with access restrictions to this directory to prevent the webserver from directly serving the file

Comment: @RajeshVishwakarma Then it makes sense. Drupal by default does not have access permissions per file, so it inherits the permissions from the entity it is attached to. If a user can see the node, he can also see any private files attached to the node. In Drupal 7 this could be solved with [file entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity), which allowed permissions to be set per file type. For Drupal 8 I am not sure yet. They are moving [media entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity) to core, but it is not yet complete. For now media entity might still work.